# Which workspace files belong in version control?

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, catkin-workspace

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I ran `catkin_make` to set up a Catkin workspace, and it created `build`, `devel`, and `src` directories. I checked `devel` and `src` into Git.

Now I'm less sure about `devel`, because the files contain paths that are specific to my system.

I recognize that most of the time you would want to put each package in a separate repo, but in this case I would like to just have a repo for my workspace, because it is just tutorial code that is not reusable.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/333042/which-workspace-files-belong-in-version-control?/) by [rgov](https://answers.ros.org/users/45623/rgov/) on ROS Answers with karma: 130 on 2019-09-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-09-14**:
Please see whether #q264600 (or any of the linked Q&As there) answer your question.

If it does, please close this as a duplicate.

**Comment by [rgov](https://answers.ros.org/users/45623/rgov/) on 2019-09-14**:
@gvdhoorn Thanks for the pointers. I didn't see any of them that address whether `devel` should be in version control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A few of the Q&As I linked in my comment state that it's not recommended to version complete workspaces. If you want to distribute sets of packages, put them in a single repository, or use a tool like `wstool` to clone them all with a single command.

All of that is preferable over versioning workspaces, as there are literally no advantages over putting related packages into a single repository. The `src` space is just an empty directory (the `CMakeLists.txt` in there (if using `catkin_make`) is a link, and is machine and ROS version specific), and it doesn't matter whether you have sub directories in `catkin_ws/src` containing packages, or whether the package directories are in `catkin_ws/src` directly.

> in this case I would like to just have a repo for my workspace, because it is just tutorial code that is not reusable.

I don't understand how this is a rationale for wanting to version an entire `src` space.

> Now I'm less sure about `devel`, because the files contain paths that are specific to my system.

To make it explicit: no top-level directories from a Catkin workspace should be versioned directly (so neither `src`, nor `devel`, `build` or `install`). Only sub directories of the `src` space would make sense.

If you absolutely must, you could add an empty `src` directory as the root of your repository and place your packages in there. As you shouldn't version the `CMakeLists.txt` link there (see earlier comment), it will just be a directory named `src`. That doesn't make it a Catkin [source space](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/workspaces#Source_Space) though.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-09-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rgov](https://answers.ros.org/users/45623/rgov/) on 2019-09-14**:
Ok, thanks for the explicit answer.

I was a little surprised that just putting multiple packages in the top level of my repository and then cloning it into my (non-version controlled) workspace's `src/` directory worked at all, without a `CMakeLists.txt`. But Catkin seems to handle this case correctly.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-09-14**:
The tool just recursively searches for packages.